# Why Python imports cannot be resolved by Pylance in VS Code, if the package is located in a shared folder?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package, unc, pylance

I am using Pylance extension in VS Code. Some packages import cannot be resolved by Pylance. I found out that these packages are located in a shared folder and the UNC Path of this folder is in the PYTHONPATH (environment variable).

All the non-UNC Path in the PYTHONPATH are correctly treated by Pylance.

The python code is running correctly.

So I want Pylance to correctly treat the packages in the shared folder.

I tried :
`from mail import Mail`

And I have this in Pylance :
`Import "mail" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports) [Ln 16, Col 6]`

To check that the UNC Path in PYTHONPATH was the issue, I copied the packages and pasted them in a local folder. Then I added the local folder path in PYTHONPATH and Pylance was able to correctly resolve the imports.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following codes to your `settings.json` to solve this problem:

```
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "path/to/your/packages"
  ],
```

Comment: I have tried this, but could not make it works. I tried to input the UNC path in different form at different depth. This is what I have in settings.json :
`"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "\\\\server\\Gl\\DA\\Pr\\FE\\CCC",
    "\\\\host.com\\DFS\\Gl\\DA\\Pr\\FE\\CCC",
    "\\\\server\\Gl\\DA\\Pr\\FE\\CCC\\package",
    "\\\\host.com\\DFS\\Gl\\DA\\Pr\\FE\\CCC\\package",
    "\\\\server\\Gl\\DA\\Pr\\FE\\CCC\\package\\module",
    "\\\\host.com\\DFS\\Gl\\DA\\Pr\\FE\\CCC\\package\\module",
],`

Comment: Check your UNC path and package structure. Ensure that you have reload VSCode after saving the `settings.json`. If it still not work, you can try using `sys.path.append(r'\\server\shared\folder')`

Comment: I have checked my UNC path I can access them from the file explorer.
I have checked the package structure and the import is nicely resolved by Pylance when I copy paste the package in a local place instead of using the UNC path.
I have reloaded VS code multiple times before and it does not work.
I tried to add sys.path.append(r'\\server\shared\folder') in the python code, but it does not change anything as it only append to sys.path at runtime, so it does not interact with PyLance.
I also opened a Python terminal and checked the sys.path values and the UNC path are there

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error some days ago. This is how I fixed it.

1. Copy the path to your Python interpreter in your virtual environment folder.
2. Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` to open command pallete. Choose the  `Python: Select Interpreter`
3. Choose `Enter Interpreter Path`
4. Paste the path you copied. So it should look like `./<Project_Folder>/env/bin/python`. Click `Enter`

And it's solved.